# print"we don't found this letter" java with loop

Tags: java, loops

this my program

```
import java.util.*;
public class LeTter { //open class name
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner
    public static void main(String[] args) { //open main class
        char letter; //decl
        int y, x, z; //decl
        boolean check = false;
        System.out.println("Enter 8 letters: "); // print sentince
        char[] des = new char[8]; //array
        for (y = 0; y < des.length; y++) { // for without semicolon :), open for loop
            des[y] = keyboard.next().charAt(0); //initialize
        } // close for loop
        System.out.println("Enter any letter to check about it: "); //will apper to the user
        letter = keyboard.next().charAt(0); //initi
        for (x = 0; x < des.length; x++) { //for loop opens
            if (des[x] == letter) { //open if loop
                System.out.println("we found it's " + des[x] + " and the index of it is " + x);
                System.out.println("so we will show you this letters " + x + " times");
                for (z = 0; z < x; z++)
                    System.out.println(des[x] + "  ");
                check = false;
            } //close if loop
            if (true)
                System.out.println("are you sure about the letter's you enterd it? we didnt found it ");
        } // close for loop
    } //close main
} //close class
```

put if the user didn't put the letter that not look like 8 letter was enter i want to print this statement "we don't found it"
how can I do it

**example:
enter 8 letters
a s d f g h j k 
enter any letter 
t
we don't found it**  << how can I do this??

**another example:
enter 8 letters
a s d f g h j k 
enter any letter 
a
we found it**  << i did this , i want the first one ""onlly""

Answer (score 0):

I skip the input and begin from the loop of your code, change it to:

```
for (x = 0; x < des.length; x++)
{ // for loop opens
    if (des[x] == letter)
    { // open if loop
        check = true;
        System.out.println("we found it's " + des[x] + " and the index of it is " + x);
        break; // you want to show 1st one only, right?
    } // close if loop
} // close for loop
if (!check)
    System.out.println("are you sure about the letter's you enterd it? we didnt found it ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've shortened your code, as you can just add the user's input into a `char` `array`, and remove the spaces.

I used `break;` to get out of the loop once the first `char` was found, you can remove this if you want to mind multiple instance of it.

```
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter 8 letters: ");
        String letters = keyboard.nextLine().replaceAll(" ", "");
        char cArray[] = letters.toCharArray();
        System.out.println("Enter any letter to check about it: ");
        char letter = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
            if (cArray[i] == letter) {
                System.out.println("We found " + letter + " at position " + i);
                found = true;
                break; //used as you specify only to find the first one
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("Are you sure about the letter you entered? We didn't find it");
        }
    }
```

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/mpniN1)